# Regex to filter out word ending with a “string” suffix - without lookahead

Tags: ruby, regex, gitlab, re2

I am trying to come up with a Ruby Regex that will match the following string:

```
MAINT: Refactor something
STRY-1: Add something
STRY-2: Update something
```

But should not match the following:

```
MAINT: Refactored something
STRY-1: Added something
STRY-2: Updated something

MAINT: Refactoring something
STRY-3: Adding something
STRY-4: Updating something
```

Basically, the first word after : should not end with either ed or ing

---

I have been using the following regex for `GitLab` commit message for a while now.

```
^(MAINT|(STRY|PRB)-\d+):\s(?:(?!(?:ed|ing)\b)[A-Za-z])+\s([a-zA-Z0-9._\-"].*)
```

However, recently they seem to have switched to using [google/re2](https://github.com/google/re2) which does not support lookahead.

Would it be possible to rewrite this regex in way so that lookahead is not used?

Comment: Your question requires clarification. If `str` is your string and `target` is the three-line string you give after the first line, a literal interpretation of your question suggests you want `str[/#{target}/m]`, but I expect that's not what you mean. I'm guessing you want to match individual lines (not the three given lines together), including, for example, `STRY-9: Add something`. A simple example, including `str` and the desired return value, would be helpful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank a lot for taking a look. Yes, I want to math on a `single line`. So `str` would be `MAINT: Refactor something` or `STRY-1: Added something` or `STRY-4: Updating something` or `Something else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a regex which has to be aware about three endings:

1. `ed\b`
2. `ing\b`
3. `ied\b`

You have to consider existence of each single spot. For instance, `e[^d]\b` and `[^e]d\b`. Writing all of them you will come with this regex:

```
^(MAINT|(STRY|PRB)-\d+):\s*(?i:\w*(e[a-ce-z]|[a-df-z]d|i(n[a-fh-z]|[a-mo-z]g|e[a-ce-z]|[a-df-z]d)|[a-hj-z]ng|[a-hj-z][a-df-mo-z][a-cefh-z])|\w)\s([a-zA-Z0-9._\-"].*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/euOXNp/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
str =<<_
MAINT: Refactor something
STRY-1: Added something
MAINT: Refactoring something
Add something
STRY-3: Adding something
STRY-1: Add something
MAINT: Refactored something
Refactor something
STRY-4: Updating something
STRY-9:   Update something
STRY-2: Updated something
_

r = /
    ^                      # Match beginning of line
    (?:                    # Begin non-capture group
      MAINT\:[ ]+Refactor  # Match string
      |                    # or
      STRY-\d+\:[ ]+       # match string
      (?:Add|Update)       # match 'Add' or 'Update'
    )                      # end non-capture group
    [ ]+something          # match one or more spaces followed by 'something'
    $                      # match end of line
    /x                     # free-spacing regex definition modes

str.scan(r)
  #=> ["MAINT: Refactor something\n",
  #    "STRY-1: Add something\n",
  #    "STRY-9:   Update something\n"]
```

To match a space in the regular expression I've use a character class containing a space (`[ ]`). That's needed because free-spacing mode removes spaces that are not in character classes. Written in the convention way, the regular expression is as follows.

```
/^(?:MAINT\: +Refactor|STRY-\d+\: +(?:Add|Update)) +something$/
```

Answer (score -1):

Without regular expression:

```
str = "MAINT: Refactor something
STRY-1: Add something
STRY-2: Update something"

p str.lines.none?{|line| line.split[1].end_with?("ed", "ing")}
# => true
```

Comment: I specifically asked for regular expression